# Does anyone know how to authenticate users using the Blackboard REST api?

Tags: rest, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, blackboard

I'm trying to use the blackboard REST APIs on this site: https://developer.blackboard.com/portal/displayApi

However, I'm not exactly sure how to get started authenticating students. How do I authenticate blackboard students on my mobile app so that I can display their courses, grades etc... I'm assuming that I need a userId of some sort, but the site does not explain how to go about acquiring that. Do I need to use the OAuth endpoints? If so, how?

I would greatly experience any help!!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It strongly suggest this API uses OAuth2, so the first step you should take is to try and find a good OAuth2 library for your language of choice

Comment: That makes sense. But I still don't understand how the server knows who the user is.  From what I understand, the server authenticates the user but how does it know who it is.

Comment: Nevermind I think I understand now!